# Magento 2 : Selected Category Not Shows in UI Form

Tags: magento2, category, uicomponent, category-tree, ui-form

I add category selector in UI form

```
<field name="catalog">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Category</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">item</item>
            <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">3</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

It's working fine but it's not show selected value on dropdown after save.

[image]

In database save Category Id like:

[image]

Comment: Hello @PrincePatel, Did you get solution of this?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari. No still not getting any solution

Comment: Hello @PrincePatel, You have to explode `category_ids` in DataProvider file like `$page->setCategoryfieldname(explode(',', $page->getCategoryfieldname()));`.